# Flutter google map on release mode not work

Tags: android, google-maps, dart, flutter

hi to all flutter developer

my question: when I use flutter google map and when I build final and release app for android the map is not working

how I can fix this problem
please look at below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, I must enter the SHA-1 when i creating API key

Comment: Hey, where do you enter the SHA-1? The firebase console? Or the google cloud console?

Comment: @Amine +1 same question here

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key but I don't think this solves it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write flutter command screen 'flutter upgrade'. Maybe it help you to solve your issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After a very long search and mainly thanks to the help of Ruslanbek0809 I solved this problem at last.
In android/app/build.gradle I added:
shrinkResources false and minifyEnabled false to the buildTypes

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

And a miracle happened